# regex that matches simple arithmetic expressions

Tags: python, regex

i have a solution, but the only problem is that for example "7=7=7" is matched and that should not be the case.

```
^[+-]?\d+([/*+-]\d+)*([/*+-]*=(?:[+-]?\d+([/*+-]\d+)*)+)*$
```

see below of what is matched and not

these are matched and that is correct

```
456+5
0
0+0
5=0
1589+232
55+2
5+55
545454545
-12*53+1-2/5
+1+2+3=-5*2/3
000=0
18=+17/25
0-0
0*0
0/0
1/1
5/5
6*6
55/55
1/22
+55
5+5+5+5+5+5+5+5+5+5+5+5+5+5+5+5+5+5*5*5*5/5/5/5*5*5*5=5*5*5*5*5*5*5*5*5*5*5*5*5*5/5+5/5-6/5555/6
0*0*0*0*0*0*0+0=00000000*0*0
003+3*2
```

these shouldnt be matched which all of them except "7=7=7" does.

```
0=
5654*45=
*23
55++55
55+
7=7=7
18/-35
5*x
3.14159265358
```

how can i fix that the equal sign can only be there once, while also having a must that if a equal sign is there then there has to be a number after that

the answer must a regex

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you changed, "these shouldnt be matched which all of them except "7=7=7" does." to "These shouldn't be matched:". SO encourages the use of proper English, meaning correct spellings, capitalization, punctuation, and so on. You will see that, for the most part, members adhere to that standard in writing questions, answers and comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could replace the final `*` with `?`: that way it can only occur once at the most:

```
^[+-]?\d+([/*+-]\d+)*([/*+-]*=(?:[+-]?\d+([/*+-]\d+)*)+)?$
```

Be aware that your regex also allows this:

```
1+1++++++++=1
```

That doesn't seem right. I'm not sure why you have that `[/*+-]*` sitting before `=`.

You could avoid some repetition by using a negative look ahead assertion:

```
^(?!.*=.*=)[+-]?\d+(([/*+-]|=[+-]?)\d+)*$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match the follow regular expression.

```
^(?:[+-]?(?:\d+[+/*-])*\d+=)?[+-]?(?:\d+[+/*-])*\d+$
```

This does not match any string that contains more than one equals sign.

---

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/biaOxe/1)

```
^           match the beginning of the string
(?:         begin a non-capture group (A)
  [+-]?     optionally match one of the two characters in the character class
  (?:       begin a non-capture group (B)
    \d+     match one or more digits
    [+/*-]  match one of the four characters in the character class
  )         end non-capture group B
  *         execute non-capture group B zero or more times
  \d+       match one or more digits
  =         match '='
)           end non-capture group A
?           optionally match non-capture group A
[+-]?       optionally match one of the two characters in the character class
(?:         begin a non-capture group (C)
  \d+       match one or more digits
  [+/*-]    match one of the four characters in the character class
)           end non-capture group C
*           execute non-capture group C zero or more times
\d+         match one or more digits
$           match end of the string
```

---

If you were to use Python's alternative regex engine (`import regex`) you could make use of the fact that it supports subroutines (a.k.a "subexpressions"):

```
^(?:([+-]?(?:\d+[+/*-])*\d+)=)?(?1)$
```

`(?1)` causes itself to be replaced by the directives that match and save to capture group 1 (`([+-]?(?:\d+[+/*-])*\d+)`). Not only does that reduce the size of the expression, it reduces the chance of errors being introduced.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bUjjmf/1)